# JPA CriteriaUpdate with selectCase inserts HEX

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I want to update all rows of my Node-table with a conditional set with an Enum.
Here is what I wrote:

```
private void test(final ID refId) {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaUpdate<Node> updateQuery = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Node.class);
    final Root<Node> from = updateQuery.from(Node.class);
    updateQuery.set(Node_.status, builder.<Status> selectCase()
                    .when(builder.equal(from.get(Node_.pk).get(PK_.version), 1), Status.NEW)
                    .otherwise(Status.CHANGED));
    updateQuery.where(builder.equal(from.get(Node_.refId), refId));
    em.createQuery(updateQuery).executeUpdate();
}
```

But after executing the query the column 'status' is filled with some kind of hex-dump ending with either **4e4557** for **NEW** or **4348414e474544** for **CHANGED**.

If I update the columns without the selectCase(), the correct String is updated.

```
updateQuery.set(Node_.status, Status.CHANGED);
```

Am I out of luck here (as I did not find anything about the usage of selectCase() in CriteriaUpdate). Do I have to splitt my query into two or use a native one?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody seems to have this problem and I did not dive deeper into it...

I went with a native query

```
String query = "UPDATE NODE SET STATUS = 
                   CASE WHEN VERSION = 1 THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'CHANGED' END 
                       WHERE REF_ID = :refId";
em.createNativeQuery(query).setParameter("refId", refId.getId()).executeUpdate();
```